# Different Monaco editor components sharing same schema

Tags: monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

**Describe the bug**

I have 2 separate components with [Monaco editor react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react) of value `JSON`. One of the editor has a schema validation defined, **problem is another instance also validating with same schema. That instance should not have any validation/schema.**

I have created a demo on [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ftdvat?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=package.json,src%2FEditorField.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fstyle.css,src%2FSchemaField.tsx&title=React%20Starter)

```
// code showing schema validation
  useEffect(() => {
    if (schema) {
      const editorSchema = createEditorSchema(schema);
      monaco?.languages?.json?.jsonDefaults?.setDiagnosticsOptions({
        validate: true,
        schemas: [editorSchema],
      });
    }
  }, [schema]);
```

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Check editor 1 and hover to see the schema error
2. Check editor 2 which has the schema of editor 1. Problem is editor 2 is validating with its own value.

**Expected behavior**

Editor 2 which is schema field should not be validated with a schema. It should only show value. Only editor 1 should be validated

**Demo Link**

[Sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ftdvat?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=package.json,src%2FEditorField.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fstyle.css,src%2FSchemaField.tsx&title=React%20Starter)

**Screenshots**
The editor 2 should not have any validations on schema, find SS below
[image: Screenshot 2023-09-19 at 13 33 21]

**Desktop (please complete the following information):**

- OS: [e.g. iOS] - mac
- Browser [e.g. chrome, safari] - any

**Additional context**
I have a feature requirement where I render 2 editor instances. Instances one has value of JSON, instance 2 has JSON schema for first instance.

Answer (score 1):

The Monaco editor is not designed to appear multiple times on a single web page with different settings, like themes, providers or here, the validation scheme. Commands like:

```js
      monaco?.languages?.json?.jsonDefaults?.setDiagnosticsOptions({
        validate: true,
        schemas: [editorSchema],
      });
```

set values for all instances of the editor control. The only control you have is to place only one editor on a web page and switch pages between different editors, where you can also change the global settings while switching.

Comment: Thanks for the update Mike. Is there a hacky way in which I can achieve this? The UX is final where 2 editors would appear and would have a schema. Any alternate way to make both work together.

Comment: I guess if I'd know any way to circumvent that, I'd mention it here, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific use-case, but we had the same problem and solved it by generating a unique id for each editor (simply by using `useId`) and used it as a "fake filename" to differentiate between the editors:

```ts
const editorId = useId()

const onMount: OnMount = (editorInstance, monaco) => {
  monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    validate: true,
    schemas: [{
      uri: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
      fileMatch: [`${id}.json`],
      schema: editorSchema
    }]
  })
}

return <Editor
  language="json"
  path={`${editorId}.json`}
  onMount={onMount}
/>
```